# Kivy Launcher closes after loading .kv file with a working python script containing kivy code

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy

I have been learning how to use kivy as an GUI and touch navagation for android. I won't post any code, that may limit any answer that could fix the problem. The problem I'm having is that I cannnot run python scripts with a .kv file named after the Main Class (all lowercase without 'app' in its name) with the build method. Kivy Loads the files, then a black screen, then kivy quits. I have been able to run python scripts that contain kivy code and they
work.

The question is how to get the Kivy Lauuncher for android  (version '1.9.1 1' from google play) to run a python file wtih a .kv file without close after opening.

I have tried tutorals and searched on the web (this site included), even kivy's own web site, and they have not worked.

I Will be greatly appreciate with any help, ideas, or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work on your PC? Also Kivy Launcher is quite outdated. You should try using Buildozer to make an APK. Also could you share your KV file? Maybe there is an error in that. Hope I helped!